# constrained clustering of samples of different size

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I have n samples of size s1, s2, ..., sn  which may or may not follow the same distributions.
I would like to group them in K groups where K will be >= 3
FYC I have found some ideas mostly from there:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/223275/classification-of-samples-into-two-groups?rq=1

I've picked the package conclust which might solve my problem  but there's the issue my samples have different sizes. So adapting their code sample (https://rdrr.io/cran/conclust/man/ckmeans.html):

```
library(plyr)
library(conclust)

sample1 <- c(0, 0, 2)
sample2 <- c(1, 0, 3, 4, 2, 1)
sample3 <- c(1, 1)
sample4 <- c(0, 1, 6)

sample_list <- list(matrix(sample1, nrow = 1), matrix(sample2, nrow = 1), matrix(sample3, nrow = 1), matrix(sample4, nrow = 1))
data <- rbind.fill.matrix(sample_list)

mustLink = matrix(c(1, 2), nrow = 1)
cantLink = matrix(c(1, 4), nrow = 1)
k = 2
pred = ckmeans(data, k, mustLink, cantLink)
pred
```

```
Error in if (best == -1 || dd[j] < dd[best]) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I can easily workaround the error by adding `data[is.na(data)] <- FALSE` but that feels weird, at this point the small samples would have lots of 0 values and would be clustered together even if different, wouldn't they?

Long story short, what would be the way to do constrained clustering on samples of different size in R please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like:

1. define dissimilarity measure between samples
2. calculate dissimilarity matrix
3. use k+tsp (https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume7/climer06a/climer06a.pdf)

its important to note that here samples would be 'sequentially' similar (you get order for each cluster).

**sample dissimilarity measure**

```
sampleDistance <- function(s1, s2) mean(abs(outer(s1, s2, FUN = "-")))
```

**dissimilarity matrix**

```
samples <- list(sample1, sample2, sample3, sample4)
n <- length(samples)

m <- matrix(0, nrow = n, ncol = n)
for(i in seq_len(n-1))
  m[i,(i+1):n] <- sapply(samples[(i+1):n], sampleDistance, s2 = samples[[i]])

m[lower.tri(m)] <- t(m)[lower.tri(m)]
```

**k+tsp**

```
library(TSP)

k <- 2 # number of clusters

cut_tour(
  solve_TSP(
    insert_dummy(TSP(m), n = k), 
    repetitions = n * 10, 
    two_opt = TRUE
  ),
  "dummy"
)
```

**result**

```
$dummy
1 3 2 
1 3 2 

$dummy
4 
4
```

Comment: Hi det! Thanks, it sounds very interesting! I got to read, test and interpret the results using your method, but just to be clear: this does not handle the constrained issue, correct?

Comment: It handles that points within samples are within same cluster. If you want to prohibit that some samples are within same cluster you should put corresponding sample distance (in matrix m) to infinity and validate the result at the end (before `cut_tour` you should check `tour_length`, if infinity it means that there is no solution).

Comment: and then I guess if I want to make sure some samples are in  the same cluster i just need to set the distance to 0...

Comment: yeah you could do that but again you need to validate solution at the end because it might not be possible regarding to number of clusters to satisfy that constraint